# length implentation for doubly linked list, python

Tags: python

my program calls len(list), and my definition for len is as follows.

```
 def __len__(self):
    if not self.head:
        return '[]'
    else:
        return self.size
```

this is the error i get

```
 assert len(testList) == 0, "List should be empty, but length is %r" % len(testList)
 TypeError: __len__() should return an int
```

So basically i have to return '[]' when the list is empty, otherwise i need to return its length. How would i go about doing this.

Comment: Returning `"[]"` for the length of an empty list seems like you read the requirements wrong.  Why wouldn't it return 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `__len__` **must** be an `int`. So return 0 when the list is empty.

---

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__):

```
object.__len__(self)
```

> Called to implement the built-in function len(). **Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0.** Also, an object that doesn’t
>   define a `__nonzero__()` method and whose `__len__()` method returns zero
>   is considered to be false in a Boolean context.

Comment: For consistency, I would make my code to have `self.size = 0` when `not self.head` and just return `self.size` in __len__.

Answer (score 1):

`__len__` should return an `int` >= 0. See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)
That's what the error says.

You are returning a string(`'[]'`), which is not a `int` and so this error is raised.
Returning 0 will be more appropriate.